# Magento 1.7.0.2 After enable paypal standard then orders are not showing in My Account

Tags: magento, paypal, orders

I have some critical issues with magento's order. When I have enabled paypal standard payment method, after that orders are not showing in My Account section. I have enabled IPN too. But its also doesn't work for me. I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 version. And I am sure it issues created for enabled paypal standard payment.

Thank you in advanced !

Comment: Are the transactions not appearing within PayPal or Magento? What happens when you enable IPN? Did you set the correct URL that Magento recommended? Can you please provide more specific information about the problem?

Comment: Yes Patrick, Actually I have setup Paypal Standard Payment Method in magento. When I am place order with Paypal, order is going in pending payment. And this order is not showing in my account at frontend. When I am disabled Paypal Standard and place order, then its work for me and show in My account section. I have configure IPN also for it. But its not work for me.

Comment: So it's going into pending on Magento? It doesn't appear in your PayPal account at all? If you completed a PayPal payment there would be a transaction ID, can you provide that information? Magento would need IPN enabled to update after a completed payment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're saying, the pending payments are not showing in the customer dashboard. To solve this, you need to edit one config.xml from any active module, and, instead of the  tag, put this code:

```
<sales>
    <order>
        <states>
            <pending_payment>
                <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
            </pending_payment>
        </states>
    </order>
</sales>
```

Then, it shhould now show the pending payments in the customer dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Eder is nto entirely correct. You have to overwrite the core file Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml and find in line 1319 the section which defines the pending_payment.
Then add the line of code:

```
<visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
```

This is how my config.xml looks like:

```
<pending_payment translate="label">
     <label>Pending Payment</label>
     <statuses>
        <pending_payment default="1"/>
     </statuses>
     <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
</pending_payment>
```